# Сколько подписок будет создано после нескольких вызовов метода

Tags: angular

Я только изучаю Angular. И я заметил, что тут очень часто используют подписки на методы. Например:

```
getUser(id: number) {
  this.userService.getUser(id).subscribe(
    (resultService: DataResponse<User>) => {       
    ...
  });
}
```

Чтобы получить конкретного пользовтеля мы оформляем подписку на этот метод.
Допустим кто-то десять раз запросил разных пользователей. Значит функция getUser была вызвана десять раз. А что в этом случае происходит с подписками? Исходные данные каждый раз разные.
Мы получим десять разных подписок?  Или это будет одна подписка и при каждом вызове этой функции она пересоздается.

И еще один вопрос. Я много видел подобных примеров, даже на самом сайте Angular. Но ни разу не видел, что бы кто-то делал отписки - unsubscribe. Разве не надо оформлять отписку после вызова метода getUser сервиса UserService?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. На каждый вызов `getUser` новая подписка.
2. Если `getUser` это просто HTTP запрос, то после получения ответа он завершается (completed), в таком случае отписка необязательна. Но есть кейсы когда запрос долго обрабатывается, а компонент
   (который запросил данные) уже не существует, то лучше отписаться,
   чтоб не отправлять/ожидать "ненужный" запрос.